# AsyncTaskLoader - onLoadFinished() is not called

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I have an `AsyncTaskLoader`:

```
public class FakePdfLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Integer>
```

That I start with:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);
```

from an activity:

```
MyActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Integer>
```

But my method:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Integer> loader, Integer data) {
    Log.d("TEST", "finished loading " + data);
}
```

is never called. I know the ATL does `doInBackground()` and also reaches `deliverResults()` and it definitely delivers an `Integer`. Could it be that the return type `Integer` causes a problem here?

EDIT: The `Integer` has nothing to do with it, I tested that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy, I'm so stupid sometimes. In my AsyncTaskloader, I overrode deliverResult, had blindly copied it from Google's example.